# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory. Why is there still?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, web-config, node-modules

I want to run the command npm run update ..
My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
      ....,
    "update": "node src/app/xxx/yyy-zzz/update.js"
```

but I have such an error

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Project\temp'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Project\\temp'
}
(node:10204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at findPackage (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Projct\xxx\src\app\xxx\xxx-update\update.js:79:21)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Projct\xxx\src\app\xxx\xxx-update\update.js:27:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without 
a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10204) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

path is good. Please help.
Looking for an answer I found the command

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you made a typo in posting your source code but the path doesn't go to the same place.

```
Users\xxx\Desktop\Projct\xxx\src\app\xxx\xxx-update\update
'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Project\temp'
```

Specifically how Project is spelled. It seems that all your projects are stored in "Projct" but the computer is looking at "Project"